# JPA Self Join using JoinTable

Tags: spring, jpa, jpa-2.0, dao, toplink-essentials

I have 1 entity call Item in which I want to be able to link parent items to children.  to use a join table to create a parent/child relationship.  I haven't been able to get any good documentation on.  So if anyone has any thoughts I'm all ears.

Here is what I have... which works most of the time.

```
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {
     @Id
     private Long id;

     @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinTable(name = "ITEMTOITEM", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ITEMID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PARENTITEMID") } )
     private Item parent;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<Item> children;
}
```

At times when I want to bring back objects that are tied to this item table I am getting an error of the following:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@6669ff5 targetAction = com.assisted.movein.web.common.nav.NavAction@6edf74b7, attributes = map['method' -> 'handleEntry']] in state 'oneTimeChargesAndFeesView' of flow 'in-flow' -- action execution attributes were 'map['method' -> 'handleEntry']'; nested exception is Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b04-fcs (04/11/2008))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "PARENTITEM_ITEMID": invalid identifier

 Error Code: 904
 Call: SELECT ITEMID, ITEMSHORTDESC, EFFENDDATE, ITEMDESC, PARENTITEM_ITEMID,  ITEMTYPECODE FROM ITEM WHERE (ITEMID = ?)
    bind => [1250]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(com.domain.Item)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here I have put together the table diagram [here](http://dbdsgnr.appspot.com/app#agdkYmRzZ25ycg8LEgZTY2hlbWEY0riZAQw).

Comment: Last little caveat is that I need this to work with eclipselink and toplink-essentials.  So i'm limited to using JPA 1.0 mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of reading on JPA 2.0 I figured out that I needed a newer version of Eclipselink 2.3+ in order to support what I was trying to do.  Here is the code that actually worked in my case, but it will not work due to our dependency on an older version [EclipseLink 2.0.2].  Also another project's is still using Toplink-essentials JPA 1.0 which again does like this notation.

```
public class Item {

@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ITEMINCENTIVESMAPPING", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "INCENTIVEITEMID", referencedColumnName = "ITEMID", insertable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ITEMID", referencedColumnName = "ITEMID", insertable = false, updatable = false) } )
private Item parentItem;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ITEMINCENTIVESMAPPING", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "INCENTIVEITEMID", referencedColumnName = "ITEMID") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ITEMID", referencedColumnName = "ITEMID") } )
private List<Item> items;

}
```

Comment: To me, it looks like you have mapped two separate relationships: a unidirectional many-to-one and a unidirectional one-to-many.  Why not map a single, bidirectional relationship?  This was the solution proposed for a self-referencing many-to-many relationship (a bidirectional mapping was used): http://drag0sd0g.blogspot.com/2010/03/many-to-many-self-reference-in-java.html

Comment: How you can make custom CRUD operation on this type of model? for example get by parentItem(). Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Try to use `@JoinColumn`instead:

```
 @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "PARENTITEMID", referencedColumnName = "ITEMID")
 private Item parent;

 @OneToMany(
        cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
 )
 @JoinColumn(name = "PARENTITEMID")
 private List<Item> children;
```

Comment: I'm looking to use a Join table between parent and child entity.  I believe your mapping only allows for a single mapping of itself.

Comment: This is mapping without additional table. Each childred has link to parent.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @JoinTable is only allowed on a @OneToOne or @OneToMany or @ManyToMany, I don't think it makes any sense on a @ManyToOne.  Use a @JoinColumn, or a @OneToOne.

Also your @OneToMany does not make sense, the mappedBy must be an attribute and you have no parentItem, it should be parent, and parent should use a @JoinColumn.

Comment: James, thanks for the heads up, the mappedBy was a CAP error.  I fixed it in the original.