# how to change mysql Query include join to not using join?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

[image]

this is my mysql table

i want to get the result

[image]

i try it the this code include join when i make second picture

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ROOT'
```

i try to using this code in java spring boot but i can't using it because of join
so i want to know that how can i change the sql code without join to get the same result 
for using java spring boot

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Self Join using JoinTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216321/jpa-self-join-using-jointable)

Comment: If you use `JpaRepository` you can add `nativeQuery=true` param in `@Query` with your `SQL` as `value` param

Comment: i already do that but it is not solution for me..